# Meaning of # in Scheme number literals

Tags: syntax, scheme, racket

DrRacket running R5RS says that `1###` is a perfectly valid Scheme number and prints a value of `1000.0`. This leads me to believe that the pound signs (#) specify inexactness in a number, but I'm not certain. The spec also says that it is valid syntax for a number literal, but it does not say what those signs mean.

Any ideas as to what the # signs in Scheme number literals signifiy?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The hash syntax was introduced in 1989. There were a discussion on inexact numbers on the Scheme authors mailing list, which contains several nice ideas. Some caught on and some didn't.

http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/ftpdir/scheme-mail/HTML/rrrs-1989/msg00178.html

One idea that stuck was introducing the `#` to stand for an unknown digit.
If you have measurement with two significant digits you can indicate that with `23##` that the digits `2` and `3` are known, but that the last digits are unknown. If you write `2300`, then you can't see that the two zero aren't to ne trusted. When I saw the syntax I expected `23##` to evaluate to 2350, but (I believe) the interpretation is implementation dependent. Many implementation interpret `23##` as 2300.

The syntax was formally introduced here:

http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/ftpdir/scheme-mail/HTML/rrrs-1989/msg00324.html

EDIT

From http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/ftpdir/scheme-reports/r3rs-html/r3rs_8.html#SEC52

> An attempt to produce more digits than are available in the internal
>   machine representation of a number will be marked with a "#" filling
>   the extra digits. This is not a statement that the implementation
>   knows or keeps track of the significance of a number, just that the
>   machine will flag attempts to produce 20 digits of a number that has
>   only 15 digits of machine representation:
>
> 3.14158265358979#####   ; (flo 20 (exactness s))

EDIT2

Gerald Jay Sussman writes why the introduced the syntax here:

http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/ftpdir/scheme-mail/HTML/rrrs-1994/msg00096.html

Comment: +1, much more useful than mine, but I'll leave it for the links. Is this specified anywhere else in RnRS?

Comment: It is difficult to find much. One tidbit is from the R3RS manual on the format section. If an implementation is asked to write a number with 20 digits, but only 15 digits in the internal representation is known, then it can write # in place of the unknown digits. Since `write` can produce these numbers, the procedure `read` must also handle these.

Answer (score 8):

Here's the R4RS and R5RS docs regarding numerical constants:

- [R4RS 6.5.4 Syntax of numerical constants](http://people.csail.mit.edu/jaffer/r4rs_8.html#SEC53)
- [R5RS 6.2.4 Syntax of numerical constants](http://people.csail.mit.edu/jaffer/r5rs_8.html#SEC54).

To wit:

> If the written representation of a number has no exactness prefix, the constant may be either inexact or exact. It is inexact if it contains a decimal point, an exponent, or a "#" character in the place of a digit, otherwise it is exact.

Not sure they mean anything beyond that, other than `0`.